# Unable to register a user from iOS Client to Ejabberd Server - XMPP

Tags: ios, ubuntu, xmpp, ejabberd

I made an EJabberd server up and running. I am writing a simple chat client in iOS where I try to register an user. But I am not able to register an user. I am sure the request is hitting the Ejabberd server.

The Log in server is below

```
=INFO REPORT==== 2014-04-25 10:46:51 ===
I(<0.381.0>:ejabberd_listener:281) : (#Port<0.3853>) Accepted connection {{211,28,44,250},52988} -> {{172,31,0,235},5222}

=INFO REPORT==== 2014-04-25 10:46:52 ===
I(<0.398.0>:ejabberd_c2s:802) : ({socket_state,gen_tcp,#Port<0.3853>,<0.397.0>}) Failed authentication for ioc1@localhost
```

[image]

Any idea how to do this? Is this related to authmethod?

This is what I have in ejabberd.cfg

```
{host_config, "localhost", [{auth_method, [anonymous]},
                                 {anonymous_protocol, sasl_anon}]}.
```

The following is the log from XCODE

```
2014-04-25 20:46:49:384 iPhoneXMPP[1971:90b] SEND: <auth       xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl" mechanism="DIGEST-MD5"/>
 2014-04-25 20:46:49:620 iPhoneXMPP[1971:650b] RECV: <challenge xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">bm9uY2U9IjMzNzkzODUwOTEiLHFvcD0iYXV0aCIsY2hhcnNldD11dGYtOCxhbGdvcml0aG09bWQ1LXNlc3M=</challenge>
 2014-04-25 20:46:49:621 iPhoneXMPP[1971:650b] SEND: <response xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">dXNlcm5hbWU9ImlvYzEiLHJlYWxtPSJsb2NhbGhvc3QiLG5vbmNlPSIzMzc5Mzg1MDkxIixjbm9uY2U9IkMzN0U0NjlBLTg0RUUtNEY3RS1CNTEzLTM5RUJFREU0NzQ3NCIsbmM9MDAwMDAwMDEscW9wPWF1dGgsZGlnZXN0LXVyaT0ieG1wcC9sb2NhbGhvc3QiLHJlc3BvbnNlPTQzYTY5OTVlZmY2Y2UwNzA0YmJkNWM4OWZiNGU5ZDQ1LGNoYXJzZXQ9dXRmLTg=</response>
2014-04-25 20:46:49:865 iPhoneXMPP[1971:4953] RECV: <failure xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><not-authorized/></failure>
2014-04-25 20:46:49:865 iPhoneXMPP[1971:90b] iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate: xmppStream:didNotAuthenticate:
2014-04-25 20:46:49.865 iPhoneXMPP[1971:90b] num--680
2014-04-25 20:46:49.866 iPhoneXMPP[1971:90b] elements--(
"<username>ioc1@localhost</username>",
"<password>ioc</password>",
"<name>ioc1@localhost</name>",
"<accounttype>1</accounttype>",
"<devicetoken>680</devicetoken>",
"<email>ioc1@localhost</email>"
)
```

Any info will be very helpful for me. Not sure where I am going wrong
Thanks and appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to register(create) a new (persistent) user, or log in to (previously created) existing account? Or you does not want to care and want anonymous temporary logins without persistent accounts? 
Your ejabberd now configured to accept anonymous logins, but you are trying to authenticate existing user. If you are using XMPPFramework and want to get temporary login, just use `[xmppStream loginAnonymously:]` and server will log you in with temporary ID.

But if you want to use persistent accounts database, you need to change `auth_method` to something else (check ejabberd documentation), create user (you can create it on the server side, or register new user from client, or use existing user's database from different application) and only then you can authenticate with given username and password.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. What I need is to register an user. I don't have any user in DB. What I need to do is register an user from the server and see the user in the register table. so, in this scenario, I need to create a new persistent user.

Comment: At this point of time, I am not looking for any authentication. I am looking to register the user from the client. I searched the documentation but was not fruitful. Could you please let me know the direction in which I need to go so that i can crack this. I am following your footsteps ( you gave me an answer for the pref. Ejabberd question). I installed Tkabber and I am able to see the chats. But for some reason, I am not able to register a new user from iOS client

Comment: You can **not** register a user until your ejabberd misconfigured. You should set up proper `auth_method`, e.g. `internal`, which will enable internal users database and will allow you to register both from client and server side (run `ejabberdctl register --help` on the server to check how register user there, and see `[xmppStream registerWithPassword:]` in XMPPFramework to register from client). From existing client, e.g. Tkabber, you can just enter any username and password, Tkabber will try to log in, and will prompt you to register new account if login was failed.

Comment: @Vitalyster- I am using registerWithElements. Is this not the one which I need to use. As you said, i will look into the server for help now. Thanks for that. It was something new to me

Comment: You should use `registerWithElements` only when your server have custom registration form with non-standard required fields. By default, ejabberd accept registration only with username and password and `registerWithPassword:` should work perfectly. In fact, `registerWithPassword:` uses `registerWithElements:` internally, you just need to write less code :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I don't have any custom form at the server end. Was breaking my head the whole day. Will jump on to registerWithPassword. Thanks once again.

Comment: @Vitalyster- I tried all possible scenarios. Still not able to resolve this issue by registering an new user. Confused why authmethod comes to play during registration as I am not going through any login at this stage.

Comment: Ironially, I am able to login. I created a login screen and I am able to login and see my roster. It is only registration which is giving the issue. Very sure this has to do something with the cfg file. Can you please send me a cfg file for this scenario. It will be really a good help for me. Thanks

Comment: Hey @TimothyRajan, were you able to solve the above issue? I'm facing a similar kind of issue.